# How to block and do not propagate containsMouse property of MouseArea to parent?

Tags: qml, qt5, mouseevent

You should keep parent-child relationship in order to propagate `MouseArea`'s move events to other `MouseArea`s that overlaps and are lower in the visual stacking order. [*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#exited-signal)

But how to do the opposite, that is how to block move signals if I do not want to share move events, so parent MouseArea doesn't `containsMouse` when child does (assuming both have `hoverEnabled: true`)?

**Edit:**

Here's little example app to illustrate what I'm talking about.
 Basically I'm looking for some elegant(qml only if possible, but any solution would be appreciated) way for outer `MouseArea` (`ma1`) to have `containsMouse` equal to `false` while mouse is over inner MouseArea.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow{
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    MouseArea {
        id: ma1

        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        MouseArea {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: parent.width * Math.log(2)
            height: parent.height * Math.log(2)
            hoverEnabled: true
            z: 1

//            onPositionChanged: mouse.accepted = true;
//            onMouseXChanged:  mouse.accepted = true;
//            onMouseYChanged:  mouse.accepted = true;
//            onEntered: { ma1.hoverEnabled = false; ma1.enabled = false; }
//            onExited: ma1.hoverEnabled = true;

            Component.onCompleted: bg.createObject(this, { "hovered": Qt.binding(function() { return containsMouse; }) } );
        }

        Component.onCompleted: bg.createObject(this, { "hovered": Qt.binding(function() { return containsMouse; }) } );
    }

    Component {
        id: bg

        Rectangle {
            property bool hovered: false

            anchors.fill: parent
            color: hovered ? "green" : "red"
            border.width: 1

            Text {
                anchors {
                    top: parent.top
                    horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
                text: (!parent.hovered ? "un" : "") + "hovered"
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide some code samples you've already tried for better understanding of what are you going to get?

Comment: added an example! @troyane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to **Qt Support**, there is no way to do this with `containsMouse` property while keeping parent-child relations between two `MouseArea`s.

> ...the workaround for this situation can be breaking the parent-child
>   relationship or having another [custom] property...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, requested feature should work out of the box. Each time you stuck on something, try to create separate project from the scratch.

Take a look at a [bit simpler code](https://github.com/troyane/StackOverflow-pro/tree/master/MouseAreas) I've prepared for you. It is pure QML. Also, since all is placed in logical order -- there is no need to provide stacking order (`z` parameter).

Comment: Im looking for the approach that would work for `MouseArea`s with parent-child relationships. I have 'parent' part in the question, but I agree that I didn't emphasize that enough, my bad. I know that hover is not shared between non-related MouseArea's or that you can write some custom property as simple as `hovered: ma1.containsMouse && !ma2.containsMouse`, but I'm interested exactly in parent-child setup and exactly in `containsMouse` property propagation.